# How to set a max rotation on an object in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotatetransform

I am trying to make a space ship tilt upwards when it travels upwards or tilt downwards when it falls but I'm stuck this is what I have so far

```
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) //If spacebar pressed
        {
            playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * floatForce, ForceMode.Impulse); // Add force upwards to player
        }

        // Rotates upwards
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (transform.rotation.x != -maxRotation)
            {
                transform.Rotate(-rotationSpeed, 0f, 0f * Time.deltaTime);
                transform.Rotate(-maxRotation, 0f, 0f);
            }
        }
```

It just spins infinitely when I press down on the space bar...

Any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit rotation of an object, you can modify the `eulerAngles` property value.

## Example

The following script takes a couple of vectors and makes sure the object rotation remains in range between their x, y, z values.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationLimitter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private bool runOnUpdate = true;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool runOnLateUpdate = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool runOnFixedUpdate = false;
    
    [Space]
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 minRotation = Vector3.zero;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 maxRotation = Vector3.zero;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (runOnUpdate)
            LimitRotation();
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (runOnLateUpdate)
            LimitRotation();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (runOnFixedUpdate)
            LimitRotation();
    }

    private void LimitRotation()
    {
        float x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.eulerAngles.x, minRotation.x, maxRotation.x);
        float y = Mathf.Clamp(transform.eulerAngles.y, minRotation.y, maxRotation.y);
        float z = Mathf.Clamp(transform.eulerAngles.z, minRotation.z, maxRotation.z);

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: In general careful with the [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) though, in this case it should be fine, just a general note ;) Also why do you reinvent [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) ? ;)

Comment: @derHugo Was testing something else using the built in method and some values didn't get clamped properly, so I just wrote it from scratch. Guess it worked fine actually. Updated the answer.